# Can STRtOK function return a null/0 value?

Tags: sql, teradata, strtok, proc-sql

I'm trying to use the strtok function to breakout a concatenated string.
This is what I have so far. My source tables are sitting in Teradata and I'm running the code via SAS.

```
proc sql;
connect to teradata as tera ( server='XXXXXX' authdomain='XXXXX';
execute(
         update DB.Table1
         from 
       (
        select id, string_key
        from DB.Table2
        where date_time >= current_date
       ) c
set 
       country = STRTOK (c.string_key,',',1),
       Expense      = STRTOK (c.string_key,',',2),
       First_Name    = STRTOK (c.string_key,',',3),
       

) by tera
disconnect from tera
quit;
```

An example of a value in string_key is :

UK,244,Jack,Mathews

For the above example, my code has no problem creating the required output i.e:

| Country | Expense | First name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| UK | 244 | Jack |

However in instances where a value in string_key has a null value after the delimiter, the strtok function returns the next available value in the wrong column.

for e.g when string_key is :

UK,244,,Mathews

then the output I get is

| Country | Expense | First name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| UK | 244 | Mathews |

but what I want is that the First_name column should be empty as there is no value for it in the string_key.

i.e I want it is

| Country | Expense | First name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| UK | 244 |  |

Could someone pls help tweak my code such that the column populates with a null value if the string has a null value?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`STRTOK` doesn't play nicely with consecutive delimiters.  You can replace consecutive delimiters with `<delimiter><space><delimiter>.` In your case:

```
trim(strtok(oreplace(string_key,',,',', ,'),',',3))
```

Alternatively, you could use `csvld`:

```
 select
 *
 from
 table (csvld(<table>.string_key,',','')
 returns(a varchar(100), b varchar(100), c varchar(100), d varchar (100))) as t;
```

Answer (score 1):

A RegEx should work:

```
SELECT 'UK,244,,Mathews' AS string_key
  ,REGEXP_SUBSTR(string_key, '(,|^)\K([^,]*)(?=,|$)',1,1)
  ,REGEXP_SUBSTR(string_key, '(,|^)\K([^,]*)(?=,|$)',1,2)
  ,REGEXP_SUBSTR(string_key, '(,|^)\K([^,]*)(?=,|$)',1,3)
  ,REGEXP_SUBSTR(string_key, '(,|^)\K([^,]*)(?=,|$)',1,4)
;
```

See [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/N3vzjT/1)

Comment: I knew there had to be a regex solution, I just couldn't get it.  Out of curiosity, which is more efficient, regexp_substr or strtok?

Comment: @Andrew Well, it doesn't matter which is more efficient, if STRTOK is not returning he expected answer. And `oreplace(string_key,',,',', ,')` fails for `'UK,,,Mathews'` :-)

Comment: That is an excellent point, I didn't catch that.

Comment: One could still work around it by calling OREPLACE several times

Comment: @dnoeth Thank you for that! Would the RegEx work even if the last value was null
i.e UK,244,,

Comment: @userMT: oReplace: for `,,,` there's only one occurence of `,,`. In `,,,,` it will be found twice. You need a RegEx if you want overlap :-)

Comment: @Josey1979 Simply try it